# Which linux kernel system calls shows bytes read from disk

Tags: python, linux, lttng

I have a python program that read Linux kernel system calls (use Lttng), So with this program I could read all kernel calls. I have some operations and then with python program going to analyses system calls, in the operations I have some IO works, then with python program I need to know how many bytes that read from cache and how many read from disk. which system calls show me the bytes read from cache and disk?

Answer (score 0):

Handling `read`, `write`, `pread`, `pwrite`, `readv`, `writev` should be enough.

You just have to check whether the FD refers to the cache or disk. I think it would be easier in kernelspace, by writing a module, but...